# For those who oppose interfaith worship on Biblical grounds, what Scriptures do they use to show that such worship is unacceptable?

Tags: anglicanism, islam, inter-faith

This is an interesting segment from CBS News on an Episcopalian church in downtown Washington, D.C. that has invited a Muslim congregation to use their sanctuary for worship. Does the Bible speak to interfaith dialogue?

[Washington church welcomes Muslims for Friday prayers](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/muslims-washington-church-friday-prayers-ramadam/)

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately, this question doesn't work well here because different Christians will disagree on what the Bible says on this subject.  See [“Biblical basis” vs “what the Bible says about a subject”](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3973/21576) (your question is the latter type).  Instead, you can ask for the biblical basis for a particular view, or the views of a particular tradition. When you get a chance, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: According to the news story, they are letting the Muslims use their building as a place for worship, but nowhere did I see an indication that the two faiths were worshipping together.  Where did you see reference to that?  "Interfaith dialogue" and "worshipping together" are Two Different Things.  What question are you asking?  Are you asking about combined worship, or about interfaith dialogue?  @Nathaniel the problem with this question is that the header and the body of text in the question Do Not Match.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast No, either question is off-topic.  "What does the Bible say about ___" questions are always off-topic, regardless of what is in the blank.

Comment: @Nathaniel OK, then "the additional problem with this question" is as I pointed out.  This isn't the first time a question title and the question itself don't match.  I am not sure if this is a sign of deliberate dishonesty or just mental sloppiness.  Sturgeon's Law, I suppose.

Comment: This question could be re-opened with some minor tweaking. If you were to ask, for instance, "What is the basis for sharing facilities with Muslims according to the Episcopalian church?" it would be on-topic.

Comment: Your title question is right now but your example is still not at all saying that they worship together. They simply share a building at different times. I suggest you find a real example of mixed services or leave examples out and let the question stand on its own.

Answer (score 2):

In the New Testament it is written:

> **2 Corinthians 6:13–17 (KJV 1900)**
>
> Be ye not unequally yoked together with unbelievers: for what
>   fellowship hath righteousness with unrighteousness? and what communion
>   hath light with darkness? And what concord hath Christ with Belial? or
>   what part hath he that believeth with an infidel?
>
> Ye are the temple of the living God; as God hath said, I will dwell in
>   them, and walk in them; and I will be their God, and they shall be my
>   people.  Wherefore come out from among them, and be ye separate, saith
>   the Lord, and touch not the unclean thing; and I will receive you

A prohibition on worship with heretics or infidels was understood in the early Church.

The ancient canons call for any clergyman who prays with heretics to be suspended (Apostolic Canons XLV) and for any clergyman or layman who enters the place of worship of Jews or heretics to be deposed (if a clergyman) and excommunicated (Canon LXV).  Canon XXXIII of the Synod of Laodicea also states, "One must not join in prayer with heretics or schismatics".

Comment: Please don't answer questions like these - they are off-topic and can only be answered with opinions.

Comment: How is it off-topic?  He is asking what the Bible says about a specific topic.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It seems objective, but unfortunately it isn't because everyone's answers depend on their theology. The community has decided on [Meta] that these questions are off-topic.

Comment: @RAC it seems you are not allowed to ask such a question unless you preference it with something like, "What do different denominations think the Bible says about ..."  (see http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/biblical-basis-vs-what-the-bible-says-about-a-subject).   In any case, I gave you an answer from my understanding of the Orthodox Christian perspective.

Comment: @Dialogist no you gave the actual answer the OP asked for.

Comment: Excuse the lack of precision in my question. I wanted to know if any Christian denomination officially would have a problem with Muslims and Christians worshipping(separately) in the same space? If so, what is the Biblical basis for this prohibition?

Comment: @RAC - Do you mind editing your question so it actually asks that, then?  The question would be on topic if you phrased it as "For those who oppose interfaith worship on Biblical grounds, what Scriptures do they use to show that such worship is unacceptable".  The difference is that you would be narrowing the scope to be asking for a specific theological viewpoint.  As phrased, anyone can give their opinion on what the Bible says.  If you want an answer from the perspective of those who oppose such worship, you need to ask that.  Then the question is OK and this answer still fits.

Comment: @RAC Please edit your question to reflect what you said in this comment.  That may allow the question to be re-opened.